# How does “npm” run “npm test code coverage”?

Tags: npm-scripts

When I execute `npm test --code-coverage`, test actually runs but doesn't generate a coverage report. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `npm run test --code--coverage` and check the result. Let me know if it works

Comment: No, coverage doesn't generate also with the above command. But I tried with ng test --no-watch --no-progress --code-coverage and works.

Comment: npm test -- --coverage worked for me!

Comment: `npm run test --code--coverage` appears to conflict with watch mode, which is why @learner needed to use `ng test --no-watch --no-progress --code-coverage`